# Capturing gestures with accessibility features on (such as explore-by-touch)

Tags: android, accessibility, gestures

We have an application which captures gestures (currently using the `onTouch` event callback, works great). Sadly, when turning on accessibility features on (such as explore-by-touch), only some of the fingers are recognized by our application. We of course have reasons to believe this is not due to a bug in our code. To us, the visually-impaired and blind populations are very important, and the gestures are even more important for them.

How can gestures be captured when accessibility features are enabled?

Comment: were you able to find solution? 
Can you share it with us?

Comment: Several suggestions were found either online, or in private mailing lists. None that were tried have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this myself (disclaimer), but from the ["Handling custom touch events"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html#custom-touch-events) section in the [Accessibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html) docs it looks like you'll need to implement a "virtual view hierarchy" by overriding `getAccessibilityNodeProvider` (assuming you have some custom views, or you're overriding onTouch in built in views, which has a similar net effect).

There is a good deal of info on the docs on that, and that works back to Android 1.6 via the support library. I'd look into all that first and get very familiar with detecting when the accessibility stuff is enabled and when it isn't, and react accordingly when it is.